# Borland C++ TComboBox

Tags: return-value, tcombobox

if have a problem with my Borland C++ 6 and a form.

In my project I have a list of members of a group that are inserted into a TComboBox. So far so good. Now I want to access the objects inside when I change the entry in this TComboBox. Now here's the problem:

**Box1->Items->Strings[Box1->ItemIndex]** returns the string of the person I chose. But when I want to access the Objects inside Box1 with

**Box1->Items->Objects[Box1->ItemIndex]** this will always return NULL...

In the last versions of the project it worked well. I tripple checked every object, every SQL everything I could think of. But nothing changed in context to the TComboBox so that this will return nothing anymore like it did before...

Do you guys have an idea what could possibly go wrong here?...